# join not working properly - missing some results

Tags: mysql

Good evening to all of you.

I have the following issue with two tables joined.
First table NAMES:

```
id--name
1--John
2--Lucy
3--Ken
```

Second table WHAREHOUSE:

```
id_name--quantity--close
1--80--1
1--20--1
1--50--0
2--10--1
```

The query is the following

```
SELECT NAMES.id, NAMES.name, sum(WHAREHOUSE.quantity) AS qty, WHAREHOUSE.close
FROM NAMES JOIN WHAREHOUSE ON NAMES.id = WHAREHOUSE.id_NAME 
GROUP BY WHAREHOUSE.close
```

The query runs fine if in WHAREHOUSE I have only first two items. The third one is not selected even if it should be. The result of the query is:

```
id--name--qty--close
1--John--100--1
1--John--50--0
```

but there should be also the following line

```
2--Lucy--10--1
```

I cannot see where I am doing wrong... hope anyone of you could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` should also be on NAMES.id

```
SELECT NAMES.id, NAMES.name, sum(WHAREHOUSE.quantity) AS qty, WHAREHOUSE.close
FROM NAMES JOIN WHAREHOUSE 
ON NAMES.id = WHAREHOUSE.id_NAME 
GROUP BY NAMES.id, WHAREHOUSE.close
```

Comment: Right! This works! Too tired to see it myself, better quit coding for today! :D

Comment: Thank you @LelioFaieta, kindly accept if you like the answer :)

Comment: As soon as I will be able to... actually it's in 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `group by` clause is wrong:

```
SELECT   NAMES.id, 
         NAMES.name, 
         SUM(WHAREHOUSE.quantity) AS qty, 
         WHAREHOUSE.close
FROM     NAMES 
JOIN     WHAREHOUSE ON NAMES.id = WHAREHOUSE.id_NAME 
GROUP BY NAMES.id, NAMES.name, WHAREHOUSE.close
```

Comment: why you have added NAMES.name in GROUP BY, every user will have a unique id as it is a primary key

Comment: @Rockse This is done to follow proper ANSI SQL standards. In any other database, a query **without** it in the group by would be illegal. In MySQL, adding it does not change anything (as you noted), except making it a bit easier to port to other databases (and to understand, of course :-))